# How to fetch data from one cluster to another cluster in dask cluster?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, dask, distributed-computing

I have created a 1st cluster using this in my jupyter notebook:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(name='clus1',n_workers=1,dashboard_address='localhost:8789')
client = Client(cluster)
```

Then read my data using pandas. and performed some preprocessing.

After that, I created 2nd cluster in 2nd jupyter notebook.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(name='clus2',n_workers=1,dashboard_address='localhost:8790')
client = Client(cluster)
```

Now I want to fetch the data from one cluster to another cluster.

is there any way around it?

Comment: Why not just have one cluster?

Comment: We want to parallelize the training task. Let's say we have 5 clusters. and all those 5 clusters are connected to one cluster that has preprocessed data. and in that way, we can train 5 different ML models simultaneously.

Comment: Interesting, but not immediately obvious why there has to be 5 clusters (instead of 1 cluster with 5x workers), since workers can train independent models. (in theory at least)

Comment: Any idea about finding out the worker's name?
I am able to get the worker's address but need to know the name also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @mdurant, another option (if appropriate for the problem at hand) is to re-use the same cluster:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(name='clus1',n_workers=1,dashboard_address='localhost:8789')
client = Client(cluster)
client.write_scheduler_file('tmp_scheduler.dask')
```

Then in the relevant sections, you could connect to the cluster (from multiple notebooks):

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(scheduler_file='tmp_scheduler.dask')
```

This obviates the need to transfer files between clusters (as data is on the same cluster).

Comment: I tried that. But while accessing the dd (Dask dataframe) from another notebook, it is not recognizing the data.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to persist to a commonly accessible location, if the transferred data is not needed elsewhere, this could be a [python tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: I have used data persist. But my another notebook is not recognizing that data.